# vuejs-datepicke style broken in a table

Tags: vue.js

DatePicker working OK everywhere in my VueJs Application. But when I try to set it in a table.
Like the Below Code -

```
<tr><td>
    <datepicker></datepicker>
</td></tr>
```

Its alignment is broken like this -
[image]

If I remove the bootstrap default `table` class from
`<table class="table">` tag. Its works fine.

Comment: Solved by adding the code - td{ white-space: normal; }

Answer (score 2):

This is because its conflicting with something in your css. The datepicker is absolutely positioned so the table does not affect it.

Just check if your `<td>` has `white-space: nowrap;` - it should depend on this.

Comment: Thanks. It's solved by adding the code - 
td{
    white-space: normal;
}